# When I run my Maven-managed project, Maven gives me some alerts that make me worried. Is there any work being done to eliminate these alerts?

Tags: codenameone

When I run my Maven-managed CodeNameOne project, Maven gives me some alerts that make me worried.

The alerts are:

[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.iw.mobile:iwcareapp-javase:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.codenameone:codenameone-core:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 60, column 19

[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.codenameone:codenameone-javase:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 70, column 19
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

[WARNING]

[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.

[WARNING]

**Are these alerts deserve attention?
If yes. Is there any work being done to eliminate them?**

Comment: This is a relatively simple warning that as far as I know is necessary for compatibility across versions of Maven. Removing the duplication should be easy if such a future version ever comes out.

Comment: Thank you, Shai for your comments.
 Please, could you register this comment as an answer? That way I can check it as an acceptable response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relatively simple warning that as far as I know is necessary for compatibility across versions of Maven. Removing the duplication should be easy if such a future version ever comes out.